# IPN mercado pago não notifica

Tags: php

Boa noite.

Eu estou usando o código sugerido pelo MP para ser como base da minha implementação da IPN.

Já fiz todos os testes de integração e

```
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");

$merchant_order = null;

switch($_GET["topic"]) {
    case "payment":
        $payment = MercadoPago\Payment::find_by_id($_GET["id"]);
        // Get the payment and the corresponding merchant_order reported by the IPN.
        $merchant_order = MercadoPago\MerchantOrder::find_by_id($payment->order->id);
        break;
    case "merchant_order":
        $merchant_order = MercadoPago\MerchantOrder::find_by_id($_GET["id"]);
        break;
}

$paid_amount = 0;
foreach ($merchant_order->payments as $payment) {   
    if ($payment['status'] == 'approved'){
        $paid_amount += $payment['transaction_amount'];
    }
}

// If the payment's transaction amount is equal (or bigger) than the merchant_order's amount you can release your items
if($paid_amount >= $merchant_order->total_amount){
    if (count($merchant_order->shipments)>0) { // The merchant_order has shipments
        if($merchant_order->shipments[0]->status == "ready_to_ship") {
            print_r("Totally paid. Print the label and release your item.");
        }
    } else { // The merchant_order don't has any shipments
        print_r("Totally paid. Release your item.");
    }
} else {
    print_r("Not paid yet. Do not release your item.");
}
```

Pelo que entendi do código, nesse trecho abaixo, eu consigo pegar qual o status do pagamento, só que ele vem vazio com compras reais

```
$paid_amount = 0;
foreach ($merchant_order->payments as $payment) {   
    $status = $payment['status'];
    if ($payment['status'] == 'approved'){
        $paid_amount += $payment['transaction_amount'];
    }
}
```

**Cole adm, porque fechou minha pergunta? Essa pergunta que você me indicou, quando eu olhei, não tinha resposta e a mesma pessoa respondeu a mesma coisa...**

Answer (score -1):

Fala irmão, beleza?
Meu sistema também estava retornando erro 500 em alguns pagamentos.
Testei cada trecho do código agora e encontrei uma solução...
O que eu fiz foi remover a seguinte linha:

```
$merchant_order = MercadoPago\MerchantOrder::find_by_id($_GET["id"]);
```

depois disso, está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Opa amigo, beleza. Obrigado pela dica, vou testa-la amanha

Comment: teste aí, cara e me dê um retorno...
porque se te ajudar também, é bug na API.
Ainda estou no modo sandbox, mas acredito que não irá mais acontecer.

Comment: Qualquer coisa a gente faz um report lá pro MP

Comment: Mas seguinte, pelo que entendi, ela que pega faz para pegar o status do payment, como tu fez pra pegar isso?

Comment: No meu aqui, a linha de código que recebe o status do pedido é essa:
 $payment = MercadoPago\Payment::find_by_id($_GET["id"]);

Depois, eu verifico o status pra poder atualizar no meu banco de dados:

if ($payment->status == 'approved'){
            print_r("O pagamento foi aprovado!");
...

Comment: vou testar então mano... ai te dou ideia

Comment: Ou, tu ta ai ? ahahah

Comment: $paid_amount = 0;
    $status = $payment->status;
    if ($payment->status == 'approved'){
        $paid_amount += $payment['transaction_amount'];
    }
   

isso em tese funcionaria?

Comment: Bicho, isso dai não funciona direito... certeza que é o retorno certo? tipo... isso dai é o retorno do pedido, eu preciso pegar o retorno caso haja uma nova ordem de pagamento